# How to incorporate mapply with nlsLM in R?

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to fit my model`y~exp((a*x1+b*x2+c)^d)+f` but I getting an error as I am not sure how to incorporate `mapply with nlsLM` from Package:minpack.lm

ERROR:

```
     Error in fn(par, ...) : 
       unused arguments (x1 = c(0.203114295490632, -0.16516023916803, 
             0.0870323364177826,
```

More explanation with different structure of the data:

So the first call to fun should be:`y[1,1,],x1[1,1,],x2[1,1,]`:fit the model using these value and give the results.then go to next call and do the same:`y[1,2,],x1[1,2,],x2[1,2,]`...etc

Comment: Does `fun(x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)` work?

Comment: If `y` is a list, select the element containing what you want, e.g. `y[[1]]`.

Comment: Where in the docs for `nlsLM` does it say it accepts arguments named `x1`, `x2`, and `y`?

Comment: I think you need to organize the data differently when passing it to `mapply`. Can you expand on what data you expect to be used on the first call of `fun`? It is not clear to me what exactly will be passed in each call to `fun`.

Comment: I had a long comment with proposed things to test until you cleared things up with your edit. I'm a little confused now, but it's clear to me that everything I was thinking before was under incorrect assumptions of your data. Have you been able to get `fun` to work manually?

Comment: By manually, I mean: can you successfully execute the code that would do the first batch only of regression? I cannot get it to work manually, likely because I am neither familiar with `nlsLM` nor with your data structures. My unposted comment will do no good since it does not make sense with your edited (3D) data.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like nlsLM requires a data.frame for its data argument (which is more consistent with model fitting), try:

```
fun <- function(x1, x2, y) {
      out <- nlsLM(y~exp((a*x1+b*x2+c)^d)+f, data = data.frame(x1=x1,x2=x2,y=y),
           start = list(a = 3, b = 0.1, c=0.02,d = 1,f=0.02))
    }
 out=mapply(fun, x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)
```

Comment: I get two errors with this: `lmdif: info = 0. Improper input parameters` and `Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model`.